# Error starting cluster: Catalog was not initialized in expected time period

Tags: impala

Currently I encountered the following error while starting Impala cluster.
Command:

```
$ ./start-impala-cluster.py --verbose
```

Output:

```
...
Waiting for Catalog... Status: 1 DBs / 0 tables (ready=False)
Waiting for Catalog... Status: 1 DBs / 0 tables (ready=False)
Error starting cluster: Catalog was not initialized in expected time period.
```

When I opened start-implaa-cluster.py, the metric value for 'catalog.num-tables' was always zero. May I know how I could deeply look into and fix the issue?

I referred the "Building Impala" document: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IMPALA/Building+Impala

I am using CentOS 7 now.

Thanks,
Jinchul

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by myself :)

The catalog information should be aligned with Hive Metastore.
It means Impala may not connect Hive metastore. I could find a clue from log files under ${IMPALA_HOME}/logs/cluster.

As for configuration files,

- Check /etc/impala/conf if you install Impala via CDH.
- Check ${IMPALA_HOME}/fe/src/test/resoucers if you build and install Impala using source code.

For your information, Cloudera Impala user guide definitely gave me good advise to understand how it could work. Please refer the link or do googling with the keywords {cloudera + impala + pdf}

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/PDF/cloudera-impala.pdf

Thanks,
Jinchul